# Can I test retina devices by setting content css property with media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, retina

Does anyone see anything wrong with setting the `content` css property on `body` when on retina device for the purpose of running retina-specific js?

This seems to me like the simplest, lightest, cross-browser solution for testing for retina devices. At least it's worked for me...

CSS:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    body {
      content: 'retina'
    }
}
```

Test with jQuery:

```
var isRetina = $('body').css('content') == 'retina';
```

Comment: Not trying to split hairs here, but "retina" is simply a marketed name of a high resolution display on Apple devices. What you really want to seek is high resolution displays on all mobile (tablet & phone) devices. Resolution of mobile devices will vary; some will be higher or lower than a Apple "retina" display. Either way, the pixel-ratio method will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.devicePixelRatio`. If it more than 1 - it's `retina` display.

For IE 10+ (which IE are available on tablets and smartphones) you can relay on [`screen.deviceXDPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533721(v=vs.85).aspx) and `screen.logicalXDPI`:

```
window.devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio ||
                        window.webkitDevicePixelRatio ||
                        screen.deviceXDPI/screen.logicalXDPI  ||
                        1;
```

Comment: Definitely want to add a fallback if window.devicePixelRatio doesn't exist. For example, only IE11 actually has that property available.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html IE9 and IE10 do not support window.devicePixelRatio and http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries shows media query support until you get to IE8

Comment: I updated my answer for IE. IE 9 and 8 a not available on high resolutions devices.