# How can I run a certain JavaScript (jQuery) function based on screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I need to run some jQuery on my site, and I need to run jQuery with different values if the user is viewing the site on a retina display. I found matchMedia - which I know how to use for certain widths, but can I do this based on screen resolution (i.e. if the user is using an iMac, run this jQuery, if not, run this other jQuery)?

I tried using window.devicePixelRatio, but I'm sure this is wrong. Am I in the right direction or totally off?

ETA - I got it working with the code below. Thanks imvain2!

```
 let detectRetina = window.devicePixelRatio
    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    parallaxfx();
})
    

    function parallaxfx() {
        let wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(detectRetina === 2) {
        $('.parallaxed1').css('top', -325+(wScroll*0.05)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed2').css('top', -650+(wScroll*0.2)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed3').css('top', -1130+(wScroll*0.3)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed4').css('top', -700+(wScroll*0.1)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed5').css('top', -1010+(wScroll*0.2)+'px')
            }
        else {
        $('.parallaxed1').css('top', -125+(wScroll*0.05)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed2').css('top', -650+(wScroll*0.2)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed3').css('top', -1130+(wScroll*0.3)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed4').css('top', -700+(wScroll*0.1)+'px')
        $('.parallaxed5').css('top', -1010+(wScroll*0.2)+'px')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I test retina devices by setting content css property with media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944121/can-i-test-retina-devices-by-setting-content-css-property-with-media-queries)

Comment: Yes, it took me a bit to get it, but window.devicePixelRatio with an if/else statement did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're likely better off using css media queries for this.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   css styles that need to be altered for mobile go here!
}
```

You can also use min-width in the media query to apply stiles to large screens only.

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
   css styles that need to be altered for destop go here!
}
```

And also there are ranges.

```
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   css styles for screens within this range go here!
}
```

Comment: I'm using a jQuery plugin that I need to change the values of - so CSS media queries don't help me here.